# In ZF2 how to make view functions to run in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-view, zend-controller

I wanted the functionalities of view files to run in controller file also.

For example, I wanted `$this->escapeHtml()` which runs in view file alone to run in controller through some means like `$this->...->escapeHtml()`

Is this possible? Kindly help.

Comment: Try `$vhm = $sm->get('viewhelpermanager')`, then `$escaper = $vhm->get('escapehtml')` and at last `$myString = $escaper('string to escape')`

Comment: @Sam brief and accurate as always :)

Comment: Thank you Sam and Stoyan Dimov. One query: will there by any issues with case sensitivity? For example, Sam has used 'viewhelpermanager' (no caps) and Stoyan used 'ViewHelperManager' (camelcased)

Comment: @Beniston No, internally all names will be normalized into lowercase, no-special-char, strings. So: `ViewHelperManager` equals `viewhelpermanager` equales `view-helper-manager`equals `View\Helper\Manager`. See https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L103 and https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L704 and https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L413

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to get the `ViewHelperManager` and extract the `EscapeHtml` helper. This is a one example how to do it from the controller:

```
$viewHelperManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager');
$escapeHtml = $viewHelperManager->get('escapeHtml'); // $escapeHtml can be called as function because of its __invoke method       
$escapedVal = $escapeHtml('string');
```

Note that it is recommended to escape and display the output in the view scripts and not in the controller.